# String interpolation outputs enum name instead of value

Tags: vb.net, enums, string-interpolation

I was hoping someone can explain this default functionality regarding string interpolation and the enum type.

I have this enum:

```
public enum CommentType
{
    MyComment = 24,
    TheirComment = 25,
    AnotherComment = 26
}
```

I am using it in a string:

```
Dim sDateModified As String 
sDateModified = $"<div name='commenttype{CommentType.MyComment}'></div>"
```

I was expecting `CommentType.MyComment` to be evaluated and the int value `24` to be used. The result should be: `<div name='commenttype24'></div>`

But what actually happens is that the identifier is used instead, giving me: `<div name='commenttypeMyComment'></div>`

In order to get the enum value I had to convert it to an integer:

```
sDateModified = $"<div name='commenttype{Convert.ToInt32(CommentType.MyComment)}'></div>"
```

It just feels counter intuitive to me. Can someone explain or point me to documentation on why it works this way?

Comment: That's what `Enum.ToString()` returns.

Comment: @SLaks Oh ok so when it resolving it using `Enum.ToString`. That makes sense.

Comment: Something else to be aware of is that an enum can contain an out-of-range value (e.g. `CommentType foo = (CommentType)17`. in this case `$"{foo}"` returns "17"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're getting the string value `MyComment` because that's what is returned by:

```
CommentType.MyComment.ToString()
```

Methods like `String.Format` and `Console.WriteLine` [will automatically call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3010662/3191599) `ToString()` on anything that isn't already a string. The string interpolation syntax `$""` is just syntactic sugar for `String.Format`, which is why string interpolation also behaves this way.

Your workaround is correct. For slightly more compact code, you could do:

```
CInt(CommentType.MyComment)
```

Answer (score 11):

You just need to use a format string in the interpolated value to force the result to integer format.

```
Dim sDateModified As String 
sDateModified = $"<div name='commenttype{CommentType.MyComment:D}'></div>"
```